# How to control any embedded video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I scraped some videos, and displayed them with iframes. That works well, however, I am now looking for a way to control these videos on my react app.
What i mean by control is for instance: pause, play, currentTime in video...etc.

I have tried several things so far.

- html5 tags, but it does not work mp4 video link that I have.
- A few packages, like jplayer or player.js.

I am pretty sure I can achieve my goal, I guess I just need to find the right tool.

EDIT: Here is a example of my code with video.js

```
            <video
                    id="my-player"
                    class="video-js"
                    controls
                    preload="auto"
                    poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
                    data-setup='{}'>
                <source src="https://openload.co/embed/myvideo" type="video/mp4"></source>
                <p class="vjs-no-js">
                    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
                    web browser that
                    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
                    supports HTML5 video
                    </a>
                </p>
            </video>
```

Comment: Could we see your HTML5 code for the purpose?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at video.js. It will give you a complete control over your video playback. Take a look at their advanced examples.
Also, you don't need iframes to work with videos. If that is a design decision then it's fine but you can do video embeds without iframes.

To control video player instance via js refer to following

JS

```
var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');
```

HTML

```
<video id="example_video_1" data-setup="{}" controls="">
  <source src="my-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Then you can control the player instance like following

```
myPlayer.play();
myPlayer.pause();
myPlayer.currentTime(120);
```

Please look at the player API in the following link

https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html

Please look at react component implementation in the following link

https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html

Comment: I have also tried videojs, please look my code, I edited my post.

Comment: @Jérémy add more details to answer.

Comment: I actually think that it is working, the problem might come from the videos I try to display. it is a video blob: blob:http://videoblabla/. Like here https://superuser.com/questions/1297267/downloading-blob-videos, but I am wondering if there is a tool that allow me to display this kind of video...

Comment: @Jérémy for that take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890088/video-js-play-a-blob-local-file-the-client-created-with-createobjecturl